# Installing .ttf font in Windows

Tags: windows, mac, fonts, arabic, truetype-fonts

I want to use a Mac font (Geeza Pro.ttf) in Windows 7 but I can't install it. If I use one of the online converters, the font gets installed but I can't use it - word crashes.

Where can I get the windows version of "Geeza Pro" font? Or a utility that converts fonts for use in Windows.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried converting (or re-saving) the font yourself by using [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/)? It's free and the only way I've ever successfully converted mac fonts to windows fonts.

Comment: Ok, but compilation will be a pain. Mac or Windows binary available anywhere?

Comment: You bet. Check them out on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/files/fontforge-executables/). It's easier to install on mac because you don't have to mess around with cygwin. These install-files are some two years old, but they should get the job done.

Comment: If that  fails, you could always try [finkproject.org](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/fontforge)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you install it? What doesn't work?

---

The standard way to install a font (and I believe .ttf's should work...?) is by heading to `C:\WINDOWS\Fonts` and then selecting `File` > `Install New Font..`. Browse to the downloaded .ttf in that window and open it to install.

Is that what you tried and didn't work? At what point did it fail?

Comment: Yes, did that, didn't work.

Comment: Ok but what didn't work? At what point did it fail? Were you unable to follow the instructions completely because there was no option? Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this one?: 
http://www.eaglefonts.com/geeza-pro-ttf-20545.htm
I do not have probably support for these characters so I see only purple rectangles :-) However, the ttf fonts should be compatible - I normally share some free ttf fonts between various Windows versions and Linux distributions and newer had problems. I use LibreOffice and on some machines OpenOffice.org but as I know it also worked in MS Word.